# ClassNotFound exception in wildfly 13 server

Tags: java, wildfly

I want to use some third party jars in my application which is hosted on **Wildfly 13** server. So i have added the module dependency in **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file for those jars which are present in wildfly modules folder and rest jars are packaged with the application WEB-INF/lib folder.

But when i am running the application, jars present in WEB-INF/lib folder are not getting referred.For which i am getting **ClassNotFound** Exception. Any reference or suggestions to achieve the above requirement is appreciated.